# Java generics - Type casting issue

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I have a generic method which accepts class type and fields of that class to be updated.
For ex:

```
class A {
  private int a;
  private int b;
}

class B {
 private int c;
 private int d;
}
```

At run time, if we pass class type as "A.class" and fieldstoBeUpdated as "b", what is the best way to access the field's getter/setter of that particular class, so that we can modify the fields.

```
public <T> void find(T clazz, List<String> fieldsToBeUpdated) {
List<T> collectionList = findAll((Class<T>) clazz);
collectionList.parallelStream().forEach(p -> {
        if (clazz instanceof A) {
            fieldsToBeUpdated.parallelStream().forEach(classFieldName -> {
                switch(classFieldName) {
                case "a":((A)p).setA(10);
                break;
                case "b":((A)p).setB(20);
                break;
                }
            });
        }

        if (clazz instanceof B) {
            fieldsToBeUpdated.parallelStream().forEach(classFieldName -> {
                switch(classFieldName) {
                case "c":((B)p).setC(30);
                break;
                case "d":((B)p).setD(40);
                break;
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

I have written above code to achieve the same.

But the problem is that i have 30 such classes to be passed as a parameter to this generic method with list of fields of that class to update/modify.

Its not the correct implementation to write 30 such if statements checking for the class type and then type casting the object to that class.

Is there any better way to achieve the same ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a side note, this doesn't look like a good use of `parallelStream`. You don't have that many fields to update so the performance is probably worse, and your `forEach` lambda [modifies shared state without any sort of thread-safety](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the suggestion given by @Mena, i came up with a solution using the reflection API.

I am iterating through the list of fieldsToBeUpdated parameter and in each iteration i am checking if the field is present in the object( passed as parameter ) using the below piece of line :

This will return the field object if present else null.

```
null != clazz.getDeclaredField(field)
```

Below is the entire implementation logic :

```
public <T> void find(Class clazz, List<String> fieldsToBeUpdated) {
    List<T> collectionList = db.findAll((Class<T>) clazz);
    if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(collectionList)) {
        collectionList.stream().forEach(p -> {
            fieldsToBeUpdated.stream().forEach(field -> {
            Date date = null;
                try {
                 if (null != clazz.getDeclaredField(field)) {
                        Field f = clazz.getDeclaredField(field);
                        f.setAccessible(true);
                        date = (Date) f.get(p);
                    }
                } catch (NoSuchFieldException|SecurityException|IllegalArgumentException|IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `A` and `B` classes seem to both provide `set/getCreatedTime` and `set/getUpdatedTime` methods.

If the other 28 or so classes provide those as well (as implied by your question), simply have a common interface featuring those methods, for all classes to implement.

Then you can bind the generic type of your method to that interface, and forego all `instanceof` statements and subsequent explicit casting.

The only drawback would be if you have a field name in your `List` that does not pertain to the concrete class being passed to the method.

If you want to enforce this, you can use reflection on the object to discover whether the field is present by name. Then, you can easily handle any missing field this with a logged warning (or whichever mechanism you deem appropriated).

**Note**

As mentioned by [thijs-steel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6422729/thijs-steel), if your "time" methods share the same implementation, you can have your 30 classes extend a common abstract parent that only implements the "time" methods.

Or, you can use `default` methods since you're clearly using Java 8.

**Example**

```
interface I {
    // assuming parameters and return types here
    public void setCreatedTime(ZonedDateTime z);
    public void setUpdatedTime(ZonedDateTime z);
    public ZonedDateTime getCreatedTime();
    public ZonedDateTime getUpdatedTime();
}

// A, B etc. all implement I

public <T extends I> void find(T object, List<String> fieldsToBeUpdated) {
    fieldsToBeUpdated
    .parallelStream()
    .forEach(
        field -> {
            switch(field) {
                case "a": {
                    try {
                        object.getClass().getDeclaredField("a");
                        // we're good
                        object.setCreatedTime(...);
                    }
                    catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                        // TODO something
                    }
                    break;
                }
                // ...
            }
        });
}
```

**Update**

If your classes share no common fields at all, you may want to change the whole approach altogether.

Instead of having a "one-generic-method-fits-all" logic implementation paradigm, you may want to use inheritance and have your own implementation of the `find` method in every single class.

That would allow for a smaller `switch` statement in each implementation, with error handling performed on the `default` case.

You could also still generalize the behavior by still having a `find` method taking a `T extends Findable` (where `Findable` declares the "time" methods **and** now the `find` method), and simply invoke `find` on the given `T` object.

Or even separate concerns between `Findable` and `Timed`, and have your classes implement both.

Comment: Instead of an interface, actual class inheritance might be even better

Comment: @ThijsSteel indeed, if the "time" methods have a common implementation.

Comment: none of those 30 classes has similar fields. As described in example the classes will be having different fields.

Comment: @SindhuraGudarada I see, that was not clear to me. See my edit for an alternative approach.

Answer (score 0):

I would extract an interface first:

```
public interface TimeManipulator {
    public void setCreatedTime(long createdTime);
    public long getCreatedTime();
    public void setUpdatedTime(long createdTime);
    public long getUpdatedTime();
}
```

and apply it to the classes:

```
class A implements TimeManipulator {
    ...
 }

class B implements TimeManipulator {
    ...
 }
```

Then all you need to do is to bind the `T` to this interface:

```
public <T extends TimeManipulator> void find(T p, List<String> fieldsToBeUpdated) {
    fieldsToBeUpdated.parallelStream().forEach(field -> {
        switch(field) {
        case "a":
        case "c":
            p.setCreatedTime(TimeUtils.toGMT(p.getCreatedTime(), ZoneOffset.of("+05:30")));
            break;
        case "b":
        case "d":p.setUpdatedTime(TimeUtils.toGMT(p.getUpdatedTime(), ZoneOffset.of("+05:30")));
        break;
        }
    });
}
```